# How to Check if scrollbar reached a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to add the function when the scroll bar reached the particular div.

How to check the scroll bar reached the particular div

Comment: You can use `scrollTop()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have such markup

```
<div>
  <div id="one">One and first</div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
  <div id="three">Three and last</div>
</div>
```

Using vanilla JS, this can be done to save the position of your target element, I targeting #two, and then test current scrolling offset if it reaches the target position.

```
const ofsetOfTwo = document.getElementById('#two').offset().top; 
window.onscroll = function(e) {  
   if (window.scrollY === divTowPosition) {
      //Do stuff...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the offset and compare with current scroll, try

```
var targetOffset = $("div").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
        // Do stuffs here
    }
});
```

you can refer [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).